# Non embedding of $Y\times Y$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I know that this is a well known result, but where can I find a proof? I am also interested to see more general non-embedding results of this type.

> **Theorem.** *Let $Y$ be the union of two segments with one segment being
>   attached in the middle of the other one. Then 
>   there is no topological embedding of the space $Y\times Y$
>   into $\mathbb{R}^3$.*

It was a homework problem in my undergraduate (sophomore) topology class taught by Professor [Karol Sieklucki](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/osoba/463) at University of Warsaw!

Comment: Do you remember what was covered in this course?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin This was a standard course of topology of metric spaces, but there were 4 IMO students in the class and the problems were far beyond of what was covered in lectures. Another problem was the Moore-Young theorem: https://mathoverflow.net/a/27248/121665

Comment: Okey, did you get to homology groups (maybe I am wrong, but it looks like a senseless pain without them).

Comment: @AntonPetrunin We did not cover homology groups, but I am interested in any solution. "it looks like a senseless pain without them", yes the problems were cruel, but inspiring.

Comment: You say the result is well-known. Could you point to where it is stated in the literature?

Comment: No idea. For me this is a folklore result and I do not know any references. This is why I ask.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz maybe one should ask Sieklucki directly?

Comment: Piotr, the question can be essentially equivalently asked about embeddings into $S^3$. Years ago, Professor Karol Borsuk asked about the non-embeddability of nice products $\ X\times Y$ into $S^n$. As I remember, He got the first result for starters, then others followed (not too many of them), including one or both parents of Greg K., then I presented a strong result during a conference in Auburn (AL) but didn't publish it; then someone from Poland published a similar but weaker result -- that's all I remember at this moment; I will not recall much extra later after all these years.

Comment: "two segments with one segment being attached in the middle of the other one" is not the most elegant way to describe this space. (:-)

Comment: Hm, perhaps Professor Karol Borsuk asked about the embeddings into products $\ S^k\times S^n$ (or even into similar products of several spheres) -- it's been years ago).

Answer (score 43):

If it did embed as $Y \times Y \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, then you could choose a sufficiently small sphere $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered at the point $(y_0,y_0)$, where $y_0$ is the point in where the two segments are glued.  Then $S \cap Y \times Y \subset S$ is an embedding of the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$ into a two sphere.  But this graph is not planar, which is a contradiction.  This argument seems to assume the embedding is sufficiently nice, e.g. simplicial with respect to some triangulations of $Y \times Y$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Maybe others can share a different argument that is valid for any topological embedding.

Comment: Could you elaborate why the embedding is $K_{3,3}$. I don't quite "see" this.

Comment: Think of $Y$ as consisting of three edges $E, F, G$ glued at a vertex $v$.  A small sphere in $Y$ centered at $v$ consists of three points, one for each of $E,F,G$.  A small sphere in $Y \times E$ centered at $(v,v)$ consists of four points, $E,F,G,E'$, where $E'$ lies in $\{v\} \times E$.  All of $E,F,G$ are joined to $E'$ by arcs, one for each of the squares $E \times E$, $F \times E$, $G \times E$.  The same is true in $Y \times F$ and $Y \times G$.  Now glue these three spaces together (along $Y \times \{v\}$) to form $Y \times Y$.  The spheres fit together to form $K_{3,3}$.

Answer (score 25):

Theorem 10 of "An Alternative Proof that 3-Manifolds Can be Triangulated" by R.H. Bing [Ann. of Math. Vol. 69, (1959), pp. 37-65] states that any topologically embedded simplicial 2-complex $K$ in a triangulated 3-manifold $M$ is near a PL embedding of $K$ into $M$.

In particular, a $2$-dimensional finite simplicial complex has a topological embedding in $\mathbb R^3$ if and only if it has a PL embedding in $\mathbb R^3$.  Together with Robert Bell's answer this resolves the question.

Answer (score 7):

I will show that $Y^k$ cannot embed in $\mathbb{R}^p$ when $p < 2k$.

Write $\mathrm{Conf}(2,X) = \{(x,x') \in X^2 \, | \; x \neq x'\}$ for the deleted diagonal of $X$, and note that any injection $Y \hookrightarrow X$ induces an $S_2$-equivariant map $\mathrm{Conf}(2,Y) \to \mathrm{Conf}(2, X)$.

We need the following corollary of [Theorem 1.8 from my paper "Configuration space in a product"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.08894.pdf).

> If an embedding $A \subseteq B$ induces a homotopy equivalence of pairs $(A^2, \mathrm{Conf}(2,A)) \simeq (B^2, \mathrm{Conf}(2,B))$, then it also induces a homotopy equivalence $\mathrm{Conf}(2,A^k) \simeq \mathrm{Conf}(2,B^k)$ for all $k \geq 0$.

Here is a short proof of the corollary in the case $k=2$.

Two points in $A^2$ are distinct if and only if they are distinct in their first coordinate, or their second coordinate, or both.  In other words, $\mathrm{Conf}(2,A^2)$ is covered by the two open subsets $A \times \mathrm{Conf}(2,A)$ and $\mathrm{Conf}(2,A) \times A$, and the intersection of these sets is $\mathrm{Conf}(2,A) \times \mathrm{Conf}(2,A)$.  As a consequence, $\mathrm{Conf}(2,A^2)$ is the homotopy pushout of a diagram that depends only on the pair $(A^2, \mathrm{Conf}(2,A))$.  By our assumption, the inclusion $A \subseteq B$ induces a pointwise homotopy equivalence on these pushout diagrams, and hence on homotopy pushouts.  This concludes the proof for $k=2$; the case of general $k$ requires a larger homotopy colimit, but is otherwise similar.

"Reordering the cars in the driveway twice" gives an equivalence $\mathrm{Conf}(2,Y) \simeq \mathrm{Conf}(2, \mathbb{R}^2)$, (even when restricted to the driveway and a little part of the street, two cars may wind around each other), leading to an equivalence of pairs
$$
(Y^2, \mathrm{Conf}(2,Y)) \simeq (\mathbb{R}^4, \mathrm{Conf}(2,\mathbb{R}^2))
$$
induced by the usual inclusion $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.  By the corollary, $\mathrm{Conf}(2, Y^k)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathrm{Conf}(2, \mathbb{R}^{2k})$, and moreover, this map is $S_2$ equivariant.

Since $\mathrm{Conf}(2, \mathbb{R}^{p}) \simeq_{S_2} (S^{p-1}, \tau)$, where $\tau$ denotes the antipodal action, and similarly $\mathrm{Conf}(2,Y) \simeq_{S_2} \mathrm{Conf}(2, \mathbb{R}^{2k}) \simeq_{S_2} (S^{2k-1}, \tau)$, any embedding $Y^{k} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ induces an $S_2$-map
$$
(S^{2k-1}, \tau) \to (S^{p-1}, \tau),
$$
which is impossible for $p<2k$ by the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your proof. I will read it carefully, but I need time (busy).